# How to extract VIEW DETAILS of messages sending out from MCE journey?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

How can I extract this view details information below inside the journey?
Does MCE provide any data view for this?

[image: VIEW DETAILS in the Journey]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the UI, you can switch to History tab where there is a funnel icon to filter out Journey name, Journey version, activity type,...

Once you get the desired result, you can extract it in CSV file by clicking the download button.

Comment: Thank you @Duc Le, rather than UI, does MCE has any features that I can use in automation e.g., data views?